# Customizing the setbreakpoint functionality in eclipse or any other code editor

Tags: python, c, eclipse, adobe-brackets

I need to customize the set breakpoint functionality. I am open to using any editor. What I need is when the breakpoint is set, I need to insert a specific text on that particular line. When the breakpoint is toggled I need to remove the text on that line. I have decided that to achive this, the editor needs to be open source since I need to tap into the functionality of the set_breakpoint() method. The code is in c, but I am open to any other editor also, which does not handle C but is easy to customize.
I have looked at:

- Eclipse
- https://github.com/adobe/brackets
- Netbeans.

All of the above seem too complex for this task. Does anyone have any suggestions? Is there a lightweight editor I could build myself for this? I am just looking for pointers on how to proceed and what would be the right editor to choose since all I need is if I click on a line text needs to be inserted without being visible to the user(like a breakpoint setting/toggling in eclipse)

UPDATE:

```
a();
b();--> breakpoint inserted here
c();
```

It should look like this:

```
a();
//Breakpoint inserted
d();--> Function call and a comment
b();
c();
```

Comment: What does insert text on line mean?

Comment: I see. But why? Line numbers between your editor window and the debugger's will differ when you add lines.

Comment: Its a little more than debugging with breakpoints. The idea is the device I am using doesnt have a debugger or debug device support. So I have written a custom function which will stop the device from executing when called. But instead of simply calling it I wanted a more elegant way of setting breakpoints. I wont be using the debugging editor at all